# disable display error in php and show only trigger error

Tags: php

how to show only trigger_error in php

I am using this code

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$divisor = 5/0;
//echo $divisor;
if ($divisor == 0) {
  echo    trigger_error("Cannot divide by zero", E_USER_ERROR);
}
```

now the output of this code is

```
Warning: Division by zero 
Fatal error: Cannot divide by zero
```

However I want to show only our own trigger error and do not want to show php error how can i do this. Thanks

Comment: is trigger_error() is your custom function try error_reporting(0)

Comment: Nothing to be display then

Comment: `$divisor = 5/0 or die trigger_error("Cannot divide by zero", E_USER_ERROR);`

Comment: Why not check for the value of divisor first before the division?

Answer (score 1):

Call `error_reporting(0)` to disable the errors in the output. They will still show in the error.log if configured.

Check http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php for more parameters to show different levels of errors if you want.

Update:

```
error_reporting(0);
$divisor = 5/0;
//echo $divisor;
if ($divisor == 0) {
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
  echo    trigger_error("Cannot divide by zero", E_USER_ERROR);
  error_reporting(0);
}
```

Comment: error_reporting(0) disable all error to display, I want to see my trigger error

Comment: so enable error reporting with error_reporting(E_ALL) right before you trigger your error

Answer (score 1):

The first warning `Warning: Division by zero` occurs at the line `$divisor = 5/0;`
So, surround with try catch

```
try{
    $divisor = 5/0;
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
    echo  "Cannot divide by zero".$e;
}
```

If you don't want to use `try/catch` use `die`. If you want to show only your own error message, then use

```
$divisor = 5/0 or die ("Cannot divide by zero");
```

If you want to use `trigger_error`, then

```
$divisor = 5/0 or die trigger_error("Cannot divide by zero", E_USER_ERROR);
```

Comment: I do not want to use try catch here